# I have the function onEdit() doesn't work if multiple people are making the change at the same time?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this code in google sheets and in turn I put the code in two file. On the first file several people are working on it and on the second just for me.

It does nothing in the archive that several people are working on, that is, if I run it, it stays there. In the other it works fine, when I give it approved and rejected

```
//onEdit para que cada que hagan el cambio se lleve a cabo
function onEdit(){
//pestaña1
  var archi = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("productividad");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Asignación Free");
  var uf = ss.getLastRow();
  var datos = ss.getRange(1,1, uf, 9).getDisplayValues();
//pestaña2
  var archivos = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("productividad");
  var sa = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Asignación Pro");
  var uf = sa.getLastRow();
  var datosdos = sa.getRange(1,1, uf, 9).getDisplayValues();
  for(var i=1;i<datos.length;i++){
    if(datos[i][7]== "Aprobado"||datos[i][7]== "Rechazado"){
      let positionCell = 1;
      let isHasNoValues = false;
      var hojaDestino = archi.getRange(positionCell,1,1,9);
      while(!isHasNoValues){
        if (!hojaDestino.getDisplayValue()){
          ss.getRange(i+1,1,1,9).copyTo((hojaDestino),{contentsOnly:true});
          ss.getRange(i+1,3,1,8).clearContent();
          isHasNoValues = true;
        }else{
          positionCell++;
          hojaDestino = archi.getRange(positionCell,1,1,9);
        }
      }
    } 
  }
//de la pestaña 2
  for(var i=1;i<datosdos.length;i++){
    if(datosdos[i][7]== "Aprobado"||datosdos[i][7]== "Rechazado"){
      let positionCell = 1;
      let isHasNoValues = false;
      var hojaDestino = archivos.getRange(positionCell,1,1,9);
      while(!isHasNoValues){
        if (!hojaDestino.getDisplayValue()){
          sa.getRange(i+1,1,1,9).copyTo((hojaDestino),{contentsOnly:true})
          sa.getRange(i+1,3,1,7).clearContent();
          isHasNoValues = true;
        }else{
            positionCell++;
            hojaDestino = archivos.getRange(positionCell,1,1,9);
          }                 
      }      
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

//I have several inconsistencies, the first, it does not work in the file that I need, second, blank columns pass through the tab where the records arrive, please if someone can help me

Comment: It's not a good practice to delete and repost, instead edit the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, I was able to develop this code but I'm learning, I just need to clarify doubts because I don't understand

Comment: What doubt do you want to clarify?

Comment: By the way, instead of "book" use "file", "workbook" or "spreadsheet" (the last is the most common term on this site when referring to "libro" of Google Sheets).

Comment: because the onEdit() stays executing forever, if I execute it in another book and there is no problem. Because they pass empty cells to the productivity tab if you have the condition that only approved and rejected

Comment: In the previous one I had another function that was executed every minute but it was very slow and the blank cells thing also happened, which I don't know why or the data where the information is stored is deleted

Comment: Why you replaced `book` by `archive` (la palabra "archivo" cuando se traduce como "file")? Have you considered to use [es.so]?

Comment: :( thanks, I didn't know it existed, sorry

Comment: You might keep using this site, but for using it effectively use the most commonly used terms (instead o "book" or "archive" use "spreadsheet") and instead of adding the whole code add a [mcve] (less more, describe the spreadsheet structure, include sample data, the expected result...).

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you need to learn to debug code in Google Apps Script.

Since your onEdit function doesn't use an event object, you should be able to debug it directly (on the Google Apps Script editor, there is dropdown to select the functions, select onEdit, then click Debug).

You could add breakpoints by clicking the line number. A breakpoint will pause the execution of the script and will show in the right panel the variables and their values. You might also add `debugging` in the code (it will be ignored when the script is triggered by an edit made to the spreadsheet)

Also you could add `console.log` statements to print messages in the execution logs. I.E. you might find helpful to add the following before the if statements having `datosdos[i][7]`:

```
console.log(datosdos[i][7]);
```

Use the above tools to verify that that the data being read and the values assigned to your variables are the correct.

Resources

- [Troubleshooting: Debugging | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#debugging)

Comment: shows all the data that is, however it does not execute,that is to say that the data is fine in terms of the matrix, because everything happens fine in the file that I have for me, however the same does not happen in the other file and it is the same code

Comment: Do the debugging on the other file and compare the structure and data of both files... Are there any relevant differences? Are all the required sheets named exactly the same way?

Comment: Yes if it's the same

Comment: @HannaAmaya 1/3... "waiting" for the answers to the other 2 questions.

Comment: I'm really sorry I wanted to leave that because I couldn't, however I've already started reading again, as for the questions Are there any relevant differences? = no, it's the same code and all required sheets are named exactly the same? = yes

Comment: @HannaAmaya Make a copy of the spreadsheet where the script is working correctly, then test the script in copy... if the script works correctly the copy, use it instead of the problematic spreadsheet.